# Google Cloud "translate.NewClient: dialing: google: could not find default credentials"

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-translate

I am trying to use Google Translate API on Windows(my own computer). I have an issue with default credentials.
Error:  **translate.NewClient: dialing: google: could not find default credentials.

I have enough balance in google cloud.

I started Translate API. (API Enabled)

I added *$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH"*

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "cloud.google.com/go/translate"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func translateTextWithModel(targetLanguage, text, model string) (string, error) {
    // targetLanguage := "ja"
    // text := "The Go Gopher is cute"
    // model := "nmt"

    ctx := context.Background()

    lang, err := language.Parse(targetLanguage)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("language.Parse: %v", err)
    }

    client, err := translate.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("translate.NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    resp, err := client.Translate(ctx, []string{text}, lang, &translate.Options{
        Model: model, // Either "nmt" or "base".
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Translate: %v", err)
    }
    if len(resp) == 0 {
        return "", nil
    }
    return resp[0].Text, nil
}

func main() {
    Json_path := "C:/Users/Mels/Documents/GoogleTools/cred-9dfos6bb49f.json"
    ProjectID := "cred"
    fmt.Println("RUNNING...")
    explicit(Json_path, ProjectID)
    fmt.Println(translateTextWithModel("ja", "Hello World", "nmt"))
}

// explicit reads credentials from the specified path.
func explicit(jsonPath, projectID string) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(jsonPath))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
    fmt.Println("Buckets:")
    it := client.Buckets(ctx, projectID)
    for {
        battrs, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(battrs.Name)
    }
}
```

JSON File

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXXXXXXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "11111111111",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxx%xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: See if you really have the right env.`fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"))` before you create the client

Comment: fmt.Println("GOOGLE ACR:", os.Getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"))
OUTPUT: GOOGLE ACR: 
I checked and return null. Everything is correct but I guess missing a part on the google cloud console. 
@BurakSerdar

Comment: So your env variable is not set, apparently. Try to figure out why.

Comment: I solved the issue. I downloaded "google cloud shell SDK" and I used "gcloud auth application-default login" code. SDK provides a JSON file and I replaced it with new version.

Answer (score 1):

If the library can't find the default credentials, then you can try to create a client with the credentials path.

Even if this might not be the best option for you (although I prefer it to the env variable), it'll help you diagnose the issue a little better.

In order to create the client with a path to the credentials file, you need to import `google.golang.org/api/option`, and create the client with the [`WithCredentialsFile` option](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/option#WithCredentialsFile). Note in the docs that [the client](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/translate#NewClient) can be created with additional options:

`func NewClient(ctx context.Context, opts ...option.ClientOption) (*Client, error)`

A somewhat more complete example on how to create a client with options would be the following (apply the required parts to your current code as needed):

```go
package main

import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/translate"
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := translate.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("/path/to/your/file"))
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
    // Use the client.

    // Close the client when finished.
    if err := client.Close(); err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
}
```

(This is just a copy of the example in [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/translate#NewClient) with the additional option included.)

Comment: The same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I downloaded "google cloud shell SDK" and I used "gcloud auth application-default login" code. SDK provides a JSON file and I replaced it with new JSON file.

I do not recommend cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup instructions. Direct use Google cloud SDK.

Comment: This is a bad solution for a prod environment, since it uses a shared client (the one from the SDK), and this means you're sharing the quota with the rest of the world. At the very least, you should generate a custom oauth client and secret and use those instead of the default ones on the SDK. Still, using user credentials is not always the best option, and I would strongly suggest to use a service account for auth.

Comment: thank you for the information @jofre I will try it. it may be quota trouble next time. you'r right